# Material: A declaration can not be both 'final' and 'dynamic'

Tags: swift, xcode, cosmicmind

I have used Material Library in swift. Installed Pod and when I build the project It gives me compilation error `A declaration cannot be both 'final' and 'dynamic'`

I am using Xcode 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was Xcode issue. When I switched to Xcode 8.3.2 from Xcode 8, then above issue resolved.